# How to reference button in card component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie to React/React Native, so please go easy on me. I've been stuck on this for a little while now so could use some help. Using functional React Native by the way.

How do I reference buttons that are in a card component from another screen? Using props in the card to display the toilet object's variables isn't a problem, but the buttons that are rendered through the card I can't work out how to reference them from the component with the map. Using navigation within the card doesn't work.

**Screen that I want to reference the button in**

```
        {toilets.map((item, index) => {
          return (
          <ToiletCard 
            key={index}
            title ={item.title}
            address={item.address}
            ratings={item.rating}
            reviews={item.reviews}
            onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("ReviewViewAndCreate", item)}} 
            /* I want to reference the review button using this onPress, but right now it isn't 
            referencing either button /* 
          />
          )
        })}
```

**Card component that contains the buttons**

```
export default ToiletCard = (props) => {
    return ( 
        <View style = {styles.textContent}>
            <View style = {{padding: 15}}>
            <Text numberOfLine={1} style = {styles.listTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
            <Text numberOfLine={1} style = {styles.listAddress}>{props.address}</Text>
            <Text><StarRating ratings={props.ratings}/>{props.ratings}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Directions</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.appButtonContainerTwo}>
                <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Reviews</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
            <View style={styles.hairline}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these changes:

```
           {toilets.map((item, index) => {
              return (
              <ToiletCard 
                key={index}
                title ={item.title}
                address={item.address}
                ratings={item.rating}
                reviews={item.reviews}
                item={item} 
                navigation={navigation}
                /* pass item as prop to this component /* 
              />
              )
            })}
```

ToiletCard component:

```
export default ToiletCard = (props) => {
    return ( 
        <View style = {styles.textContent}>
            <View style = {{padding: 15}}>
            <Text numberOfLine={1} style = {styles.listTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
            <Text numberOfLine={1} style = {styles.listAddress}>{props.address}</Text>
            <Text><StarRating ratings={props.ratings}/>{props.ratings}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Directions</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate("ReviewViewAndCreate", props.item)}} 
                style={styles.appButtonContainerTwo}>
                <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Reviews</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
            <View style={styles.hairline}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dipan, I think that is probably the right way to go about it, but I'm still encountering the navigation issues I encountered before. Putting navigation in the ToiletCard component with props gives an error - it doesn't recognize navigation, because it hasn't been a parameter in the function. If I do add it as one (like you can see in the code snippet below) I get the following error - (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.title')).


export default ToiletCard = ({ props, navigation }) => {

any ideas?

Comment: How you are using props  in `ToiletCard `?

Comment: I have updated the answer it should work now.

Comment: Thank you, those changes worked. Appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome, Please mark it right/ upvote so that it can help others too :)

Comment: Can't upvote as I am new, but I have marked it right. Cheers.